# paging in gridview , 2nd page empty , gridview populated on a button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have searched this problem and non of the answers have not solved My problem.

when user types a word a word and clicks a button a SqlDataAdapter searches the database and puts the results to a datatable which populates the gridview.
When enabling the paging in gridview only the first page of gridview shows data !

here is my code. This is where my data table is defined :

```
private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    kcestring.DataSource = @"localhost";
    kcestring.InitialCatalog = "KCE";
    kcestring.UserID = "sa";
    kcestring.Password = "123";

    SqlDataAdapter searchadap = newSqlDataAdapter("sp_GetDevicePropByDeviceName2", kcestring.ToString());
    searchadap.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter categoryID = new SqlParameter("categoryID", SqlDbType.BigInt);

    categoryID.Value = drp_SubCategories.SelectedValue;

    searchadap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(categoryID);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    searchadap.Fill(dt);

    grv_Device.DataSource = dt;
    grv_Device.DataBind();
}

protected void grv_Device_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grv_Device.DataSource = dt;
    grv_Device.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    grv_Device.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was to big foe a comment !
this is my page load it contains stuff which is used in other parts of program :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        btn_Edit.Enabled=false ;
        lbl_error.Visible = false;
        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(Session["logedin"]))
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        hiddenitems.Visible = false;
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {   btn_Search.Visible = true;
            lbtn_advacedsearch.Visible = true;

            drp_Property.Visible = true;
            txt_pvalue.Visible = true;
            Label5.Visible = true;
            Label4.Visible = true;


        }

        img_Logo.Visible = false;
        //imgLogo.Src = "pics/Manufacturer_Logo/selectmodel.jpg";
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder kcestring = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        kcestring.DataSource = @"localhost";
        kcestring.InitialCatalog = "KCE";
        kcestring.UserID="sa";
        kcestring.Password="123";
        //kcestring.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        SqlDataAdapter empper = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_GetEmployeepermissionsByID", kcestring.ToString());
        SqlParameter employeeID = new SqlParameter("employeeID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        employeeID.Value = Session["employeeid"];

        empper.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(employeeID);
        empper.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable da = new DataTable();
        empper.Fill(da);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

before

```
searchadap.Fill(dt);
```

The reason is that you have defined two `dt` (One global and the other local to the event `btn_Search_Click`). On the `btn_Search_Click` event you are filling the local `dt`. `grv_Device_PageIndexChanging` event is not getting any rows because its accessing the global variable. Both are different variables.

Comment: I did so and the problem still remains .

Comment: can you post your page load?

Comment: I think this problem has somthing to do with gridview datasource , that is why I defined my dt datatable as global. But the problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside `PageIndexChanging`:

```
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Requseted_movie ORDER BY [ID] DESC", con);

    SqlDataAdapter DA1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DA1.Fill(DT1);

    GridView1.DataSource = DT1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```